# Wordpress Multisite loads wrong subdomain dashboard

Tags: multisite, subdomains, apache, virtual-hosts

**Background:**
I have a VPS where i launched multiple websites.
I then had a requirement to create a new website that will utilize the Wordpress Multisite functionality

I created my wordpress website first, and then as the requirement came, i changed it to multisite.

**My Problem:**

When i create a sub-domain site and want to view the website, i get redirected to the apache 2 default page.
When i want to access the dashboard of sub-domain site i get redirected to another website that is on the shared vps.

Does anyone know why the multisite is loading the wrong website dashboard and showing me the apache default page when i try to visit the new website ?

Comment: Did you modify your vhosts to account for the new subdomains? WP won't show you the apache default page, that's apache doing that, it sounds like your server doesn't know how to serve this new subdomain, because it hasn't been told about it, so it doesn't know to route the request to that WP install

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the reply.
How do i go about telling the server of the new sub domain ?

Comment: I don't know, I use Nginx personally, you would need to ask Apache people or refer to Apache docs, it isn't a WordPress thing. Just keep in mind that your browser doesn't talk to WordPress, it talks to Apache, and Apache passes the message to where it needs to go. You'd be best looking up vhosts and then seeing what your server has ( or contacting your host ), this isn't something that can be fixed or influenced by a WP plugin/option/filter/code in PHP